Can someone please help me with this error associated with slurm workload manager
Whenever it tries to submit a job, it repeatedly gives these errors
[amr-090:3572940] OPAL ERROR: Unreachable in file ext3x_client.c at line 112
[amr-089:780970] OPAL ERROR: Unreachable in file ext3x_client.c at line 112
[amr-090:3572967] OPAL ERROR: Unreachable in file ext3x_client.c at line 112

Please configure as appropriate and try again.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*** An error occurred in MPI_Init
*** on a NULL communicator
*** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
***    and potentially your MPI job)
[amr-090:3572858] Local abort before MPI_INIT completed completed successfully, but am not able to aggregate error messages, and not able to guarantee that all other processes were killed!

The application appears to have been direct launched using "srun",
but OMPI was not built with SLURM's PMI support and therefore cannot
execute. There are several options for building PMI support under
SLURM, depending upon the SLURM version you are using:

  version 16.05 or later: you can use SLURM's PMIx support. This
  requires that you configure and build SLURM --with-pmix.

  Versions earlier than 16.05: you must use either SLURM's PMI-1 or
  PMI-2 support. SLURM builds PMI-1 by default, or you can manually
  install PMI-2. You must then build Open MPI using --with-pmi pointing
  to the SLURM PMI library location.


Could you upload the slurm job scheduler file? It will be helpful to see how are you executing QE inside your job scheduler file.

I am seeing a similar error. I note that it occurs when I use the srun command to have slurm reserve a session from our cluster. But if I ssh into that machine from another terminal session, I can run the executable without a problem. I hypothesize that MPI_Init somehow knows that it is running under slurm, and tries to use a different initiation process.

This is not a question for here in its current form.  Can you provide a more full input example for what you submit to slurm?  Is this for a modeling code?
